# List Update - row conflict

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column called `list` which is used in my order by (in MYSQL queries) and within list is numbers: (e.g. 1 to 20)

This list is then output using MYSQL order by `list` ASC - However, when I update my list in backend using a Jquery drag drop UI list it is supposed to update the list frontend.

My problem is that my list order sometimes conflicts with other rows as there could be two or three rows with the value of 1 in list therefore when my order updates I would like to know how I can update other rows by +1 **only if the rows are >= the order number given**

I do not want to make the column primary as I am not aiming to make the `list` column unique, the reason for this is because there is more than one category - and in each category they all start at 1 - therefore if I make it unique it would cause errors because there was multiple 1's over different categories.

I asked a friend who said I could probably try PL/SQL using a trigger function but this is new grounds to me - I don't fully understand that language and was wondering if anyone could help me do what I am trying to using MYSQL or even PL/SQL.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
<?php
$project = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['pid']));
$category = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['cat']));
$order = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['order']));
// need to do update the moved result (list row) and update all conflicting rows by 1
mysql_query("UPDATE `projects` SET `cat`='$category',`list`='$order' WHERE `id`='$project'")or die(mysql_query());
?>
```

**Conclusion:**

I am trying to update a none unique column to have unique values for that individual category. I am not sure how to update all the rows in that category by +1

Comment: Would it not be easier to add a second criteria to your ORDER BY clause? `ORDER BY list ASC, category ASC`?

Comment: What difference would ordering by category make? - the reason list is there is so that projects can be placed customly on a page - meaning they could be order 1 (frontend) one day and order 5 (frontend) the next.. I only need to order the list as the admin/project manager has dragged the list in the backend to match the front end... which requires me to update `list` which when there is more than one it often then ASC by project name - which might not be how it was placed in the backend..

Comment: My point was that you can add extra columns to the ORDER BY, so that if your `list` column has 3 rows with a value of 1, you can then sort on the value of a second column. It avoids having to do messy updates. If that's not what you're after, can I ask you to add an actual example in your question, because I've read the above half a dozen times and I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@andrewsi is right, in particular I suggest `order by list ASC, last_update DESC` so in the same query where you update `list` you can timestamp `last_update` and therefore you will have not need to use triggers or any other updates.

Comment: Isn't fantastic this option but it will do.

Comment: thk, this is the straightforward way

Answer (score 2):

In general, what andrewsi and Luis have suggested is true. Instead of (like andrewsi said) "do messy updates" you should really consider ordering by a second column.

However, I can maybe see your point for your approach. One similar situation I know it could apply is in a CMS where you let the backend user order items by changing the order number manually in textfields next to the items, e.g.

```
item 1 - [ 1 ]
item 2 - [ 3 ]
item 3 - [ 2 ]
```

... the number in the `[]` would then be the new order.

So, a quite messy solution would be (many steps, but if you do not have to worry about performance it might be OK for you, I don't know):

```
INSERT INTO projects (cat, list, timestamp_inserted) VALUES (:cat, :list, NOW())
```

and then as a second step

```
SELECT id, list FROM projects WHERE cat=:cat ORDER BY list ASC, timestamp_inserted DESC
```

and then loop through the array you get from the select and foreach row update (:i is the increasing index)

```
UPDATE projects SET list=:i WHERE id=:id
```

PS: you would have to add a column `timestamp_inserted` with a timestamp value.

PPS: to clearly state, I would not recommend this and never said it is best practice (for those considering to downvote because of this)